# Without using the delete, is possible to update a Notification Channel Importance level after it was created?

Tags: android, android-notifications, notification-channel

Without deleting the channel.

After created a notification channel on Android,  is that possible to update the importance level of a specific channel though application update?
Just calling the createNotificationChannel again or reinstalling the app is not being enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

As explained in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels):

> You can't programmatically modify the behavior of a notification
>   channel after it's created and submitted to the notification manager;
>   the user is in charge of those settings after creation.

Comment: Thanks @jmart, yes it is true. The only way is creating a new channel changing its ID.

Comment: We cant even create the same channel with same id. I did it , but need some google documentation stating this .

Comment: Shame on you GOOGLE!

Comment: This is so buggy... One of our users reported that he installed the application when he had the device in spanish and when he switched the application to english the notification settings remained in spanish!

Comment: as far as I'm aware, you can simply try to create the channel again with the same id but different name to overcome the problem mentioned by madlymad. you can do it when user switches the language, so your channels are renamed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [specs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#createNotificationChannel(android.app.NotificationChannel)), you can invoke `createNotificationChannel` again, with a *lower* importance level only:

> The importance of an existing channel will only be changed if the new
>   importance is lower than the current value and the user has not
>   altered any settings on this channel.